# Remove docType declaration from output of XmlSchema .net

Tags: .net, xml, doctype

The following code:

```
        XmlSchema xmlSchema = new XmlSchema();

        XmlSchemaElement xmlSchemaElement = new XmlSchemaElement();            
        xmlSchemaElement.Name = "SomeElement";
        xmlSchema.Items.Add(xmlSchemaElement);

        XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();            
        xmlSchema.Write(stringWriter, xmlNamespaceManager);

        String result = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Gives me:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SomeElement" />
</xs:schema>`

I don't want the docType declaration.

Obviously I could just remove the first line. But, does anyone know of a way to stop the XmlSchema class from writing the docType declaration in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing directly to your `StringWriter`, write to an `XmlWriter`. That way, you can set specific serialization options.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; // <-- this is what you care about
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings);
xmlSchema.Write(xmlWriter, xmlNamespaceManager);

String result = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: + 1 awesome, this would have taken me ages to find. Thanks very much.